# How to replace a value in a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

the program asks user to enter 5 unique number, if the number is already in the list, ask for a new number. after 5 unique numbers have been entered, display the list

```
numbers = ['1','2','3','4','5']
count = 0
index = 0
while count <6:
    user = raw_input ("Enter a number: ")
    if user in numbers:
        print "not unique"
    if user not in numbers:
        print "unique"
        count += 1
        numbers = numbers.replace(index,user)
        index +=1
    print numbers
```

when the program gets to the replace method, it raise an attribute error

Comment: The [set type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) may be useful to you, since it automatically enforces uniqueness. When you try to `add` an item to a set, if it is already in the set, then it has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
numbers[index] = user
```

A list doesn't have a `replace()` method. A string does have a replace method however.

If you wish to append a number to the end of a list, you can use `append()`:

```
numbers.append(user)
```

If you wish to insert a number at a given position, you can use `insert()` (for example, position `0`):

```
numbers.insert(0, user)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to initialize a list in Python:

```
numbers = []

while len(numbers) != 5:
     num = raw_input('Enter a number: ')
     if num not in numbers:
         numbers.append(num)
     else:
         print('{} is already added'.format(num))

print(numbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace it with Subscript notation, like this

```
numbers[index] = user
```

Apart from that your program can be improved, like this

```
numbers = []
while len(numbers) < 5:
    user = raw_input ("Enter a number: ")
    if user in numbers:
        print "not unique"
    else:
        print "unique"
        numbers.append(user)
print numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the order of the numbers, you should probably look into sets. Addidionally, if you want to work with numbers, not strings, you should cast the string to an int. I would've written something like this.

```
nums = set()

while len(nums) < 5:
    try:
        nums.add(int(raw_input("Enter a number: ")))
    except ValueError:
        print 'That is not a number!'
    print 'Numbers entered: {}'.format(', '.join(str(x) for x in nums))
```

Output:

```
Enter a number: 5
Numbers entered: 5
Enter a number: 3
Numbers entered: 3, 5
Enter a number: 1
Numbers entered: 1, 3, 5
Enter a number: 7
Numbers entered: 1, 3, 5, 7
Enter a number: 9
Numbers entered: 1, 3, 9, 5, 7
```