# Replace numbers in array for specific places only

Tags: python, python-3.x

There are 32 numbers in array c and all the number are 21. I want to replace the numbers in position 0,5,10,18,21,24,28 with 63. How can I do that?

```
a =32
b = [0,5,10,18,21,24,28]
c = []
for i in range(a):
    c.append(21)
```

Comment: Have you tried `for i in b: c[i] = 21`?

Comment: What's wrong with initializing it as `c = [21] * a` instead of the loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace a value in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093845/how-to-replace-a-value-in-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Setup:

- More efficient creation of `c`, per [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)

```
a = 32
b = [0, 5, 10, 18, 21, 24, 28]
c = [21] * a
```

#### Replace values at given indices:

- `list[index]` allows for retrieval or assignment of a value to a specific `index` location in a `list`

```
for x in b:
    c[x] = 63
```

Resources:

- [Python Lists](https://realpython.com/python-lists-tuples/#python-lists)